# Virtualbox unable to install

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, virtualbox, dpkg

**The problem:** Unable to install virtual box.
I tried to install it using the following command:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox
```

Here is the outcome

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d/README is world writable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
virtualbox is already the newest version (5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up virtualbox-ext-pack (5.1.38-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
removing old virtualbox extension packs
virtualbox-ext-pack: downloading: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.38/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.38.vbox-extpack
The file will be downloaded into /usr/share/virtualbox-ext-pack
License accepted.
0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to install "/usr/share/virtualbox-ext-pack/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.38.vbox-extpack"
VBoxManage: error: The installer failed with exit code 1: VBoxExtPackHelperApp: error: World writable: '/usr'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ExtPackManagerWrap, interface IExtPackManager
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleExtPack(HandlerArg*)" at line 1201 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
Hash mismatch Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.38.vbox-extpack: expected e93d87b0f5de50369baca0a48082236b947df5b922ffd0233c0fa92c1206defd, or wrong accept-license key, removing the file.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-ext-pack (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-ext-pack
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I googled the solution and found similar problems:

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53032193/problam-with-apt-get-install) provides the following solution

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Did NOT work. Here is the outcome.

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d/README is world writable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up virtualbox-ext-pack (5.1.38-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
removing old virtualbox extension packs
virtualbox-ext-pack: downloading: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.38/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.38.vbox-extpack
The file will be downloaded into /usr/share/virtualbox-ext-pack
License accepted.
0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to install "/usr/share/virtualbox-ext-pack/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.38.vbox-extpack"
VBoxManage: error: The installer failed with exit code 1: VBoxExtPackHelperApp: error: World writable: '/usr'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ExtPackManagerWrap, interface IExtPackManager
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleExtPack(HandlerArg*)" at line 1201 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
Hash mismatch Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.38.vbox-extpack: expected e93d87b0f5de50369baca0a48082236b947df5b922ffd0233c0fa92c1206defd, or wrong accept-license key, removing the file.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-ext-pack (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-ext-pack
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[This one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/857824/cannot-install-virtualbox-extension-pack) offers the following solution:

`sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq virtualbox-ext-pack
sudo apt-get update`

Did NOT work. Same outcome appears as I try to install virtualbox.

[Ths one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020193/how-to-install-virtual-boxs-extension-pack-via-default-repository-in-ubuntu-17) provides another approach:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-ext-pack
export http_proxy='http://proxyserveraddress:port'    
export https_proxy='https://proxyserveraddress:port'
```

Did NOT work. Nothing changes.

[This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868972/virtualbox-ext-pack-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1) and [This one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862982/error-while-installing-virtual-box) offers following solution:

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Did NOT work. Same error persists.

Then I have seen [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042925/error-about-virtualbox-ext-pack-when-trying-to-install-or-uninstall-any-software) which is offers a pretty extensive solution:

```
# Oldfred's command list for cleaning and repairing

#houseclean
sudo apt-get autoclean # only removes files that cannot be downloaded anymore (obsolete)
sudo apt-get clean

#refresh
sudo apt-get update #resync package index
sudo apt-get upgrade #newest versions of all packages, update must be run first

#would upgrade you to the latest kernel in the repositories
#dist-upgrade is also able to remove existing packages if required
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

# fix Broken packages -f 
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a

# Remove lock
# If you are absolutely sure you do not have another upgrade process running.
# Locked dpkg - only if sure you are not running another update.

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a 

# added zika's tip for problems with hash sum mismatch

sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update

# added 2F4U's tips for Package Manager & Update Manager problems

Does executing these commands help?

cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get update

This will rebuild the cache.
```

Starting from `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` I get the following error:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d/README is world writable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up virtualbox-ext-pack (5.1.38-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
removing old virtualbox extension packs
virtualbox-ext-pack: downloading: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.38/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.38.vbox-extpack
The file will be downloaded into /usr/share/virtualbox-ext-pack
License accepted.
0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to install "/usr/share/virtualbox-ext-pack/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.38.vbox-extpack"
VBoxManage: error: The installer failed with exit code 1: VBoxExtPackHelperApp: error: World writable: '/usr'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ExtPackManagerWrap, interface IExtPackManager
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleExtPack(HandlerArg*)" at line 1201 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
Hash mismatch Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.38.vbox-extpack: expected e93d87b0f5de50369baca0a48082236b947df5b922ffd0233c0fa92c1206defd, or wrong accept-license key, removing the file.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-ext-pack (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-ext-pack
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I visited [virtualbox page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) and followed the instructions for "Debian-based Linux distributions", more specifically:

- added deb `https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian <mydist> contrib` to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`
- `sudo apt-key add oracle_vbox_2016.asc`
- `sudo apt-get update`

-sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.2

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d/README is world writable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgsoap8 libvncserver1 virtualbox-dkms
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Recommended packages:
  libsdl-ttf2.0-0
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  virtualbox virtualbox-ext-pack virtualbox-qt
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  virtualbox-5.2
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 73,7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 87,3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

This time I get a different error

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d/README is world writable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgsoap8 libvncserver1 virtualbox-dkms
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Recommended packages:
  libsdl-ttf2.0-0
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  virtualbox virtualbox-ext-pack virtualbox-qt
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  virtualbox-5.2
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 73,7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 87,3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial/contrib amd64 virtualbox-5.2 amd64 5.2.20-125813~Ubuntu~xenial [73,7 MB]
Fetched 73,7 MB in 32s (2.245 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                        
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 330819 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing virtualbox-ext-pack (5.1.38-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Successfully uninstalled "Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack".
VBoxManage: error: The installer failed with exit code 1: VBoxExtPackHelperApp: error: World writable: '/usr'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ExtPackManagerWrap, interface IExtPackManager, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "Cleanup()" at line 1251 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-ext-pack (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing virtualbox-qt (5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
dpkg: virtualbox: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 virtualbox-ext-pack depends on virtualbox (<< 5.1.38-dfsg-z) | virtualbox-5.1; however:
  Package virtualbox is to be removed.
  Package virtualbox-5.1 which provides virtualbox is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-5.2 which provides virtualbox is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-5.1 is not installed.
 virtualbox-ext-pack depends on virtualbox (>= 5.1.38-dfsg-0~) | virtualbox-5.1; however:
  Package virtualbox is to be removed.
  Package virtualbox-5.1 which provides virtualbox is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-5.2 which provides virtualbox is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-5.1 is not installed.
 virtualbox-ext-pack depends on virtualbox (<< 5.1.38-dfsg-z) | virtualbox-5.1; however:
  Package virtualbox is to be removed.
  Package virtualbox-5.1 which provides virtualbox is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-5.2 which provides virtualbox is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-5.1 is not installed.
 virtualbox-ext-pack dep
Removing virtualbox (5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.2) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20180209-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-ext-pack
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Finally, I downloaded the .deb file  (for ubuntu 16.04 AMD64)from [virtualbox page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) and executed

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.1_5.1.38-122592~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb
```

This results in the following:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d/README is world writable
(Reading database ... 331301 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack virtualbox-5.1_5.1.38-122592~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-5.1 (5.1.38-122592~Ubuntu~xenial) over (5.1.38-122592~Ubuntu~xenial) ...
Setting up virtualbox-5.1 (5.1.38-122592~Ubuntu~xenial) ...
addgroup: The group `vboxusers' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.5) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.2) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20180209-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
```

but when I execute virtualbox I get the following error:

```
VirtualBox: Error -610 in supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime!
VirtualBox: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so",) failed: <NULL>

VirtualBox: Tip! It may help to reinstall VirtualBox.
```

So what else should I do to install virtual box and extension pack?

**Thanks to @GAD3R the problem has found.
The problem is you have initially changed the permission of /usr and its sub-dir , your system become insucure , and the package connot be installed because of the write permission for "other"**

So I installed another ubuntu next to the troublesome one.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85463/discussion-on-question-by-burak-akdemir-virtualbox-unable-to-install).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You recive this error :

```
VirtualBox: Error -610 in supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime!
VirtualBox: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so",) failed: <NULL>
VirtualBox: Tip! It may help to reinstall VirtualBox.
```

because the permission of the root partition is changed recursively to `777`. Virtualbox set some restrictions for the file permission and ownership.

[Main.cpp : Hardening on UNIX-like OSes](https://www.virtualbox.org/svn/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/HostDrivers/Support/SUPR3HardenedMain.cpp)

> Check that all installed files and directories (both optional and mandatory ones) are **owned by root:wheel** and are **not writable by anyone except root**.